# Extract Eventlog messages in a specific language

Tags: windows-7, message, extract, event-log

I need some help regarding the extraction of eventlog data under Windows 7.

What I try to achieve:
A computer has Windows 7 German (or any other language) installed. I want to extract the eventlog messages in Englisch to transport them to another computer where I want to store and analyze the eventlog.
This should be done somehow programatically (C# or C++).

I have tried different ways. Write a C# programm to extract the messages result always in getting the messages not in englisch but the configured language of the computer. I also tried it in C++ but also with the same result.

The other approach was then to extract the eventlog in a evtx-File and transport it to another computer with an englisch operating system. But the problem with that solution is that I also need non Windows eventlog messages (e.g. from the installed programs) which cannot be viewed on the other computer where the program and the message dlls are not installed.

Does anybody have an idea how to extract eventlog messages in English independent from the language of the operating system?

Thanks a lot,
Ulli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the complete code for C++ to extract special eventlog messages in a specific language (Thanks to "Apokal" and MSDN). You can change the definitions for

1. Provider Name (this is the key in the registry)
2. Resource dll (this is the path to the message dll referenced in the registry)
3. Message language (this is the language code - Note: Seems the complete code is needed "DE" is not working "DE-de" works ...)

   ```
       #include "stdafx.h"
   #include <windows.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <strsafe.h>

   #define PROVIDER_NAME           L"SceCli"
   #define RESOURCE_DLL            L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\scecli.dll"
   #define MESSAGE_LANGUAGE        0x0409 // En-Us
   #define MAX_TIMESTAMP_LEN       23 + 1   // mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.mmm
   #define MAX_RECORD_BUFFER_SIZE  0x10000  // 64K

   HANDLE GetMessageResources();
   DWORD DumpRecordsInBuffer(PBYTE pBuffer, DWORD dwBytesRead);
   DWORD GetEventTypeName(DWORD EventType);
   LPWSTR GetMessageString(DWORD Id, DWORD argc, LPWSTR args);
   void GetTimestamp(const DWORD Time, WCHAR DisplayString[]);
   DWORD ApplyParameterStringsToMessage(CONST LPCWSTR pMessage, LPWSTR & pFinalMessage);

   CONST LPWSTR pEventTypeNames[] = {L"Error", L"Warning", L"Informational", L"Audit Success", L"Audit Failure"};


   HANDLE g_hResources = NULL;


   void wmain(void)
   {
       HANDLE hEventLog = NULL;
       DWORD status = ERROR_SUCCESS;
       DWORD dwBytesToRead = 0;
       DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;
       DWORD dwMinimumBytesToRead = 0;
       PBYTE pBuffer = NULL;
       PBYTE pTemp = NULL;

       // The source name (provider) must exist as a subkey of Application.
       hEventLog = OpenEventLog(NULL, PROVIDER_NAME);
       if (NULL == hEventLog)
       {
           wprintf(L"OpenEventLog failed with 0x%x.\n", GetLastError());
           goto cleanup;
       }

       // Get the DLL that contains the string resources for the provider.
       g_hResources = GetMessageResources();
       if (NULL == g_hResources)
       {
           wprintf(L"GetMessageResources failed.\n");
           goto cleanup;
       }

       // Allocate an initial block of memory used to read event records. The number 
       // of records read into the buffer will vary depending on the size of each event.
       // The size of each event will vary based on the size of the user-defined
       // data included with each event, the number and length of insertion 
       // strings, and other data appended to the end of the event record.
       dwBytesToRead = MAX_RECORD_BUFFER_SIZE;
       pBuffer = (PBYTE)malloc(dwBytesToRead);
       if (NULL == pBuffer)
       {
           wprintf(L"Failed to allocate the initial memory for the record buffer.\n");
           goto cleanup;
       }

       // Read blocks of records until you reach the end of the log or an 
       // error occurs. The records are read from newest to oldest. If the buffer
       // is not big enough to hold a complete event record, reallocate the buffer.
       while (ERROR_SUCCESS == status)
       {
           if (!ReadEventLog(hEventLog, 
               EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ | EVENTLOG_BACKWARDS_READ,
               0, 
               pBuffer,
               dwBytesToRead,
               &dwBytesRead,
               &dwMinimumBytesToRead))
           {
               status = GetLastError();
               if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == status)
               {
                   status = ERROR_SUCCESS;

                   pTemp = (PBYTE)realloc(pBuffer, dwMinimumBytesToRead);
                   if (NULL == pTemp)
                   {
                       wprintf(L"Failed to reallocate the memory for the record buffer (%d bytes).\n", dwMinimumBytesToRead);
                       goto cleanup;
                   }

                   pBuffer = pTemp;
                   dwBytesToRead = dwMinimumBytesToRead;
               }
               else 
               {
                   if (ERROR_HANDLE_EOF != status)
                   {
                       wprintf(L"ReadEventLog failed with %lu.\n", status);
                       goto cleanup;
                   }
               }
           }
           else
           {
               // Print the contents of each record in the buffer.
               DumpRecordsInBuffer(pBuffer, dwBytesRead);
           }
       }

       getchar();

   cleanup:

       if (hEventLog)
           CloseEventLog(hEventLog);

       if (pBuffer)
           free(pBuffer);
   }


   // Get the provider DLL that contains the string resources for the
   // category strings, event message strings, and parameter insert strings.
   // For this example, the path to the DLL is hardcoded but typically,
   // you would read the CategoryMessageFile, EventMessageFile, and 
   // ParameterMessageFile registry values under the source's registry key located 
   // under \SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Application in
   // the HKLM registry hive. In this example, all resources are included in
   // the same resource-only DLL.
   HANDLE GetMessageResources()
   {
       HANDLE hResources = NULL;

       hResources = LoadLibraryEx(RESOURCE_DLL, NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE | LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
       if (NULL == hResources)
       {
           wprintf(L"LoadLibrary failed with %lu.\n", GetLastError());
       }

       return hResources;
   }


   // Loop through the buffer and print the contents of each record 
   // in the buffer.
   DWORD DumpRecordsInBuffer(PBYTE pBuffer, DWORD dwBytesRead)
   {
       DWORD status = ERROR_SUCCESS;
       PBYTE pRecord = pBuffer;
       PBYTE pEndOfRecords = pBuffer + dwBytesRead;
       LPWSTR pMessage = NULL;
       LPWSTR pFinalMessage = NULL;
       WCHAR TimeStamp[MAX_TIMESTAMP_LEN];

       while (pRecord < pEndOfRecords)
       {
           // If the event was written by our provider, write the contents of the event.
           if (0 == wcscmp(PROVIDER_NAME, (LPWSTR)(pRecord + sizeof(EVENTLOGRECORD))))
           {
               GetTimestamp(((PEVENTLOGRECORD)pRecord)->TimeGenerated, TimeStamp);
               wprintf(L"Time stamp: %s\n", TimeStamp);
               wprintf(L"record number: %lu\n", ((PEVENTLOGRECORD)pRecord)->RecordNumber);
               wprintf(L"status code: %d\n", ((PEVENTLOGRECORD)pRecord)->EventID & 0xFFFF);
               wprintf(L"event type: %s\n", pEventTypeNames[GetEventTypeName(((PEVENTLOGRECORD)pRecord)->EventType)]);

               pMessage = GetMessageString(((PEVENTLOGRECORD)pRecord)->EventCategory, 0, NULL);

               if (pMessage)
               {
                   wprintf(L"event category: %s", pMessage);
                   LocalFree(pMessage);
                   pMessage = NULL;
               }

               pMessage = GetMessageString(((PEVENTLOGRECORD)pRecord)->EventID, 
                   ((PEVENTLOGRECORD)pRecord)->NumStrings, (LPWSTR)(pRecord + ((PEVENTLOGRECORD)pRecord)->StringOffset));

               if (pMessage)
               {
                   status = ApplyParameterStringsToMessage(pMessage, pFinalMessage);

                   wprintf(L"event message: %s", (pFinalMessage) ? pFinalMessage : pMessage);
                   LocalFree(pMessage);
                   pMessage = NULL;

                   if (pFinalMessage)
                   {
                       free(pFinalMessage);
                       pFinalMessage = NULL;
                   }
               }


               // To write the event data, you need to know the format of the data. In
               // this example, we know that the event data is a null-terminated string.
               if (((PEVENTLOGRECORD)pRecord)->DataLength > 0)
               {
                   wprintf(L"event data: %s\n", (LPWSTR)(pRecord + ((PEVENTLOGRECORD)pRecord)->DataOffset));
               }

               wprintf(L"\n");
           }

           pRecord += ((PEVENTLOGRECORD)pRecord)->Length;
       }

       return status;
   }


   // Get an index value to the pEventTypeNames array based on 
   // the event type value.
   DWORD GetEventTypeName(DWORD EventType)
   {
       DWORD index = 0;

       switch (EventType)
       {
       case EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE:
           index = 0;
           break;
       case EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE:
           index = 1;
           break;
       case EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE:
           index = 2;
           break;
       case EVENTLOG_AUDIT_SUCCESS:
           index = 3;
           break;
       case EVENTLOG_AUDIT_FAILURE:
           index = 4;
           break;
       }

       return index;
   }


   // Formats the specified message. If the message uses inserts, build
   // the argument list to pass to FormatMessage.
   LPWSTR GetMessageString(DWORD MessageId, DWORD argc, LPWSTR argv)
   {
       LPWSTR pMessage = NULL;
       DWORD dwFormatFlags = FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER;
       DWORD_PTR* pArgs = NULL;
       LPWSTR pString = argv;

       // The insertion strings appended to the end of the event record
       // are an array of strings; however, FormatMessage requires
       // an array of addresses. Create an array of DWORD_PTRs based on
       // the count of strings. Assign the address of each string
       // to an element in the array (maintaining the same order).
       if (argc > 0)
       {
           pArgs = (DWORD_PTR*)malloc(sizeof(DWORD_PTR) * argc);
           if (pArgs)
           {
               dwFormatFlags |= FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY;

               for (DWORD i = 0; i < argc; i++)
               {
                   pArgs[i] = (DWORD_PTR)pString;
                   pString += wcslen(pString) + 1;
               }
           }
           else
           {
               dwFormatFlags |= FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS;
               wprintf(L"Failed to allocate memory for the insert string array.\n");
           }
       }

       if (!FormatMessage(dwFormatFlags,
           g_hResources,
           MessageId,
           MESSAGE_LANGUAGE,  
           (LPWSTR)&pMessage, 
           0, 
           (va_list*)pArgs))
       {
           wprintf(L"Format message failed with %lu\n", GetLastError());
       }

       if (pArgs)
           free(pArgs);

       return pMessage;
   }

   // If the message string contains parameter insertion strings (for example, %%4096),
   // you must perform the parameter substitution yourself. To get the parameter message 
   // string, call FormatMessage with the message identifier found in the parameter insertion 
   // string (for example, 4096 is the message identifier if the parameter insertion string
   // is %%4096). You then substitute the parameter insertion string in the message 
   // string with the actual parameter message string. 
   DWORD ApplyParameterStringsToMessage(CONST LPCWSTR pMessage, LPWSTR & pFinalMessage)
   {
       DWORD status = ERROR_SUCCESS;
       DWORD dwParameterCount = 0;  // Number of insertion strings found in pMessage
       size_t cbBuffer = 0;         // Size of the buffer in bytes
       size_t cchBuffer = 0;        // Size of the buffer in characters
       size_t cchParameters = 0;    // Number of characters in all the parameter strings
       size_t cch = 0;
       DWORD i = 0;
       LPWSTR* pStartingAddresses = NULL;  // Array of pointers to the beginning of each parameter string in pMessage
       LPWSTR* pEndingAddresses = NULL;    // Array of pointers to the end of each parameter string in pMessage
       DWORD* pParameterIDs = NULL;        // Array of parameter identifiers found in pMessage
       LPWSTR* pParameters = NULL;         // Array of the actual parameter strings
       LPWSTR pTempMessage = (LPWSTR)pMessage;
       LPWSTR pTempFinalMessage = NULL;

       // Determine the number of parameter insertion strings in pMessage.
       while (pTempMessage = wcschr(pTempMessage, L'%'))
       {
           dwParameterCount++;
           pTempMessage++;
       }

       // If there are no parameter insertion strings in pMessage, return.
       if (0 == dwParameterCount)
       {
           pFinalMessage = NULL;
           goto cleanup;
       }

       // Allocate an array of pointers that will contain the beginning address 
       // of each parameter insertion string.
       cbBuffer = sizeof(LPWSTR) * dwParameterCount;
       pStartingAddresses = (LPWSTR*)malloc(cbBuffer);
       if (NULL == pStartingAddresses)
       {
           wprintf(L"Failed to allocate memory for pStartingAddresses.\n");
           status = ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY;
           goto cleanup;
       }

       RtlZeroMemory(pStartingAddresses, cbBuffer);

       // Allocate an array of pointers that will contain the ending address (one
       // character past the of the identifier) of the each parameter insertion string.
       pEndingAddresses = (LPWSTR*)malloc(cbBuffer);
       if (NULL == pEndingAddresses)
       {
           wprintf(L"Failed to allocate memory for pEndingAddresses.\n");
           status = ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY;
           goto cleanup;
       }

       RtlZeroMemory(pEndingAddresses, cbBuffer);

       // Allocate an array of pointers that will contain pointers to the actual
       // parameter strings.
       pParameters = (LPWSTR*)malloc(cbBuffer);
       if (NULL == pParameters)
       {
           wprintf(L"Failed to allocate memory for pEndingAddresses.\n");
           status = ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY;
           goto cleanup;
       }

       RtlZeroMemory(pParameters, cbBuffer);

       // Allocate an array of DWORDs that will contain the message identifier
       // for each parameter.
       pParameterIDs = (DWORD*)malloc(cbBuffer);
       if (NULL == pParameterIDs)
       {
           wprintf(L"Failed to allocate memory for pParameterIDs.\n");
           status = ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY;
           goto cleanup;
       }

       RtlZeroMemory(pParameterIDs, cbBuffer);

       // Find each parameter in pMessage and get the pointer to the
       // beginning of the insertion string, the end of the insertion string,
       // and the message identifier of the parameter.
       pTempMessage = (LPWSTR)pMessage;
       while (pTempMessage = wcschr(pTempMessage, L'%'))
       {
           if (isdigit(*(pTempMessage+1)))
           {
               pStartingAddresses[i] = pTempMessage;

               pTempMessage++;
               pParameterIDs[i] = (DWORD)_wtoi(pTempMessage);

               while (isdigit(*++pTempMessage))
                   ;

               pEndingAddresses[i] = pTempMessage;

               i++;
           }
       }

       // For each parameter, use the message identifier to get the
       // actual parameter string.
       for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwParameterCount; i++)
       {
           pParameters[i] = GetMessageString(pParameterIDs[i], 0, NULL);
           if (NULL == pParameters[i])
           {
               wprintf(L"GetMessageString could not find parameter string for insert %lu.\n", i);
               status = ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;
               goto cleanup;
           }

           cchParameters += wcslen(pParameters[i]);
       }

       // Allocate enough memory for pFinalMessage based on the length of pMessage
       // and the length of each parameter string. The pFinalMessage buffer will contain 
       // the completed parameter substitution.
       pTempMessage = (LPWSTR)pMessage;
       cbBuffer = (wcslen(pMessage) + cchParameters + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR);
       pFinalMessage = (LPWSTR)malloc(cbBuffer);
       if (NULL == pFinalMessage)
       {
           wprintf(L"Failed to allocate memory for pFinalMessage.\n");
           status = ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY;
           goto cleanup;
       }

       RtlZeroMemory(pFinalMessage, cbBuffer);
       cchBuffer = cbBuffer / sizeof(WCHAR);
       pTempFinalMessage = pFinalMessage;

       // Build the final message string.
       for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwParameterCount; i++)
       {
           // Append the segment from pMessage. In the first iteration, this is "8 " and in the
           // second iteration, this is " = 2 ".
           wcsncpy_s(pTempFinalMessage, cchBuffer, pTempMessage, cch = (pStartingAddresses[i] - pTempMessage));
           pTempMessage = pEndingAddresses[i];
           cchBuffer -= cch;

           // Append the parameter string. In the first iteration, this is "quarts" and in the
           // second iteration, this is "gallons"
           pTempFinalMessage += cch;
           wcscpy_s(pTempFinalMessage, cchBuffer, pParameters[i]);
           cchBuffer -= cch = wcslen(pParameters[i]);

           pTempFinalMessage += cch;
       }

       // Append the last segment from pMessage, which is ".".
       wcscpy_s(pTempFinalMessage, cchBuffer, pTempMessage);

   cleanup:

       if (ERROR_SUCCESS != status)
           pFinalMessage = (LPWSTR)pMessage;

       if (pStartingAddresses)
           free(pStartingAddresses);

       if (pEndingAddresses)
           free(pEndingAddresses);

       if (pParameterIDs)
           free(pParameterIDs);

       for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwParameterCount; i++)
       {
           if (pParameters[i])
               LocalFree(pParameters[i]);
       }

       return status;
   }


   // Get a string that contains the time stamp of when the event 
   // was generated.
   void GetTimestamp(const DWORD Time, WCHAR DisplayString[])
   {
       ULONGLONG ullTimeStamp = 0;
       ULONGLONG SecsTo1970 = 116444736000000000;
       SYSTEMTIME st;
       FILETIME ft, ftLocal;

       ullTimeStamp = Int32x32To64(Time, 10000000) + SecsTo1970;
       ft.dwHighDateTime = (DWORD)((ullTimeStamp >> 32) & 0xFFFFFFFF);
       ft.dwLowDateTime = (DWORD)(ullTimeStamp & 0xFFFFFFFF);

       FileTimeToLocalFileTime(&ft, &ftLocal);
       FileTimeToSystemTime(&ftLocal, &st);
       StringCchPrintf(DisplayString, MAX_TIMESTAMP_LEN, L"%d/%d/%d %.2d:%.2d:%.2d", 
           st.wMonth, st.wDay, st.wYear, st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond);
   }
   ```

Comment: If anybody get it work with C# and interop feel free to post :)

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to do in full way.

Here is why:

Each program that writes events to EventLog has an appropriate EventSource registered under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog. And an EventMessagFile value under EventSource key provides a path to a file that contain's event messages. So if, for example, some custom program provides only german event messages in that file, where do you get an english event messages from? The answer is from nowhere, because developers simply could not shipped event messages for other languages.

And for Windows, if you've got a german windows, but no english language pack (Microsoft's MUI) where does Windows have to get translations from? Nowhere.

Comment: We have all messages of our custom program available in englisch. But we have different keys for each language in the registry. Is that the problem? If we install the language pack we get also all the windows messages in englisch?

Comment: As far as I understood you, your program is shown under eventlog by two keys (for two languages), for example eventlog\CustomProgramEng and eventlog\CustomProgramGer. Is it right? if so, the easiest way is to merge all event messages into one file, you can have both german, english, japanese event messages into one dll and so far register only one event source (create one key), and than eventlog service depending on current culture will localize messages for you.

Comment: So you just have to export evtx file from german windows to windows where english is current language (and your custom program is registered there too) and eventlog service will take from your event message dll an english events due to english is the current system language. See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd996907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for both english and japanese messages in one file.

Comment: Unfortunatelly we cannot chage the custom program now and need a solution. I need to correct me. The custom program registers only one eventlogkey for each message dll. If the program switches the language the path to the message dll is changed to _de.dll. Which is not better :(

Comment: Has somebody ever tried to read eventlogs with the c++ api (with c# this is not supported). As far as we understood there is a way to specify the dll where the messages should be taken from. But we didn't make it work :(

Comment: are you talking about [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb427356%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) example?                                                            By the way, why do you think that C# doesn't support eventlog reading? There is a [EventLog Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx) that I've used recently, and it gives you a bunch of usefull methods.

Comment: Thanks for the sample. I finally got it working with C++ by specifying Provider name, dll and the specific language. This is not possible in C# as the special functions used are not available in C#